# asp.net core Dockerfile Environment variable

Tags: docker, asp.net-core

I have a problem settings HostingEnvironment on docker image.

When i go by this approach it does not work it just sets the Environment to the $ENVIRONMENT

```
Is Development False
Is Test False
Is Production False

info: Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime\[0\]
Hosting environment: echo $ENVIRONMENT
```

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY \["src/Customer.Console/Customer.Console.csproj", "src/Customer.Console/"\]
COPY \["src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj", "src/Contracts/"\]
COPY \["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"\]
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GH_PAT,dst=/GH_PAT \
dotnet nuget add source --username \_ --password `cat /GH_PAT` --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/owner/index.json"
RUN dotnet restore "src/Customer.Console/Customer.Console.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Customer.Console"
RUN dotnet build "Customer.Console.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Customer.Console.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
RUN export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
ENTRYPOINT \["dotnet", "LabelAPI.CustomerConsumer.Console.dll","--environment","$ENVIRONMENT"\]
```

Option 2 i just type out the Entrypoint command where it actually works but then the container crash with dependency injections.

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:6.0 AS base
WORKDIR /app

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:6.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY \["src/Customer.Console/Customer.Console.csproj", "src/Customer.Console/"\]
COPY \["src/Contracts/Contracts.csproj", "src/Contracts/"\]
COPY \["src/Application/Application.csproj", "src/Application/"\]
RUN --mount=type=secret,id=GH_PAT,dst=/GH_PAT \
dotnet nuget add source --username \_ --password `cat /GH_PAT` --store-password-in-clear-text --name github "https://nuget.pkg.github.com/owner/index.json"
RUN dotnet restore "src/Customer.Console/Customer.Console.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/src/Customer.Console"
RUN dotnet build "Customer.Console.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "Customer.Console.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish /p:UseAppHost=false

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .

ARG ENVIRONMENT
ENV ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT
RUN export ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=$ENVIRONMENT

ENTRYPOINT dotnet LabelAPI.CustomerConsumer.Console.dll --environment $ENVIRONMENT
```

```
Is Development True 
Is Test False 
Is Production False

Unhandled exception. System.AggregateException: Some services are not able to be constructed (Error while validating the service descriptor 'ServiceType: MediatR.IRequestHandler2[Application.Features.RoutingDataFeatures.Queries.Query.GetRoutingDataFromDatabaseRequest,Domain.Models.RoutingData] Lifetime: Transient ImplementationType: LabelAPI.Application.Features.RoutingDataFeatures.Handlers.Query.GetRoutingDataFromDatabaseRequestHandler': Unable to resolve service for type 'Common.Interfaces.IMongoRepository1[Domain.Models.RoutingData]' while attempting to activate 'Application.Features.RoutingDataFeatures.Handlers.Query.GetRoutingDataFromDatabaseRequestHandler'.)
```

Is it possible to use it with ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "LabelAPI.CustomerConsumer.Console.dll","--environment","$ENVIRONMENT"]

Comment: `RUN export ...` doesn't do anything, because each `RUN` statement is run in a separate shell. So when the `RUN` statement is finished, the exported variable is lost. You should use `ENV` to set environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

You must read this to understand ARG and ENV differences:
https://vsupalov.com/docker-arg-env-variable-guide/

With ARG you can define variables that scope is until the image is built but it will not be present in runtime when you start a container based on the image you built. Also you can pass ARG-s to docker build: `docker build --build-arg MYVAR=MYVALUE` given you have defined MYVAR in Dockerfile with `ARG MYVAR`

With ENV you can have variables that are present in build time and both runtime but you can not pass ENV to the `docker build` instead you need to give the value of ENV from ARG like this:

Dockerfile:

```
ARG MYVAR
ENV MYVAR=$MYVAR
```

Docker run:
`docker build --build-arg MYVAR=MYVALUE ...`

This way you will have a MYVAR variable with MYVALUE value when you start a container from this image.

However here you should set this variable on the moment you start your container and not predefine it in the Dockerfile. You can pass any environment variables to `docker run` with the -e flag:

`docker run -e ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development -e MYOTHERVAR=MYVALUE ...`